# Apache Script Directive in Directory Block

Tags: apache

I'm trying to use Apache to direct HTTP requests that target specific sub-directories into PHP scripts based on the the verb. So DELETE /res1/ would trigger a response from deleteres1script.php and DELETE /res2/ would trigger a response from deleteres2script.php.

My dev httpd.conf setup looks as follows:

```
<VirtualHost dev.local>
<Directory C:/xampp/htdocs/dev/dt >
Script DELETE /delete.php
</Directory>
<Directory C:/xampp/htdocs/dev/dt2 >
Script DELETE /delete.php
</Directory>
# Script DELETE dt.php
ServerName dev.local
DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/dev
</VirtualHost>
```

The Script directive within the VirtualHost context block seems to be fine when uncommented, but when I make a DELETE request on the res1/2 directories the default index.php is run. I've checked the remainder of the httpd.conf file and don't see anything that appears to limit this functionality. Are there an additional directives or constraints that need to modified assuming default settings for Apache 2.4  on a Windows machine?